# box-shadow not working in Safari 5

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser, mobile-safari

In This code

```
box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #000000, 0 10px 0 #1578B1;
```

this

```
0 10px 0 #1578B1;
```

Not working in Safari 5.0.5 (Windows)

Any solution

Comment: Update Safari. It works for me in 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works in the version of Chrome I'm running, so I'd venture to guess it has to do with your version of Safari (which is a little old, by the way).

I recommend adding `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #000000, 0 10px 0 #1578B1;` after your `box-shadow: 0 6px 0 #000000, 0 10px 0 #1578B1;` and see what happens. (Best practice actually dictates that the vendor specific code should be before the standard code, but your version of Safari actually appears to be be misbehaving, because it's not ignoring the whole line like it should if it doesn't understand the whole thing.)

If that still doesn't work, turn that second color to something significantly lighter. It's possible is *is* working, but your monitor is showing the blue too dark and you can't tell the difference.

I've made a fiddle for testing - http://jsfiddle.net/E28CM/1/ . As you can see, I didn't change your box-shadow code, and this code works in the browsers I have.